# Como impedir a seleção de conteúdo com CSS?

Tags: css

Como impedir a seleção de texto/conteúdo da minha página web com CSS?

Isso seria extremamente útil para botões, âncoras, tags e outros elementos que poderiam ser selecionados sem o interesse do usuário...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Utilizando as seguintes regras de CSS para os elementos que não podem ser selecionados:

```css
#seletor {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: `-o-user-select` já esta incluso em algum desses?

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei, o -webkit-user-select serve para o opera!

Answer (score -3):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RemoveSelection() 
           {if (window.getSelection) {window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();}}
    </script>
</head>
<body onmouseup="RemoveSelection();">
    Select some content on this page with the mouse!
</body>
```

Comment: Apesar de aparentemente funcionar (não testei), a pergunta pede uma solução em css, não js.